# Deleting every character after the nth occurence of a character in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

For a string `str`, how does one delete every character after the `n`th occurence of the character `c`?

For example, if `str` is `"2016-10-20"`, how could one delete every character after the 2nd occurrence of the character `-`, yielding `"2016-10"`?

Comment: What should happen in your example if there are less than 2 occurrences of `-`?

Answer (score 3):

There's no convenient `split` function in the standard library, so you essentially have to roll your own. One approach:

```
dropAfter :: Int -> Char -> String -> String

dropAfter _ _ "" = ""
dropAfter 0 d (x:xs) = ""
dropAfter 1 d (x:xs) | x == d = ""
dropAfter n d (x:xs) | x == d = x : dropAfter (n-1) d xs
                     | otherwise = x : dropAfter n d xs
```

The `split` package, though, does provide `splitOn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]`:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Data.List (intercalate)
dropAfter n d = intercalate [d] . take n . splitOn [d]
```

Answer (score 3):

The fold fiend strikes again.

```
dropAfter :: Int -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropAfter n _ _ | n < 1 = []
dropAfter n f xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs n where
  go x r !k
    | f x = if k == 1 then [] else x : r (k - 1)
    | otherwise = x : r k
```

Comment: why `(\`seq\` [])` rather than `const []`?

Comment: @rampion, it's my habit to help out strictness analysis (and therefore unboxing) when I can. That `seq` ensures that the value of the updated accumulator is always demanded. It may not be necessary in this case, but I have seen similar forms with `const` go funny once they end up in a sufficiently complicated context.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could use this as a stepping stone to start using parsers:

```
λ import Text.Parsec
λ runParser (many (noneOf "-") `sepBy` char '-') () "example from question" "2016-01-43"
Right ["2016","01","43"]
λ import Data.List
λ intercalate "-" . take 2 <$> it
Right "2016-01"
```

The nice thing about making the switch now is that, as you learn more about your input (and what it can and can't look like), it's fairly easy to update a parser to match, where using a custom function can get real hinky real fast.